# Export multiple scraped items to a csv file in selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ok so i have this code to scrape this link.... https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/storage/lenovo-storage/s3200/70l8/parts/display/compatible. The code I have scrapes all the details perfectly.......except the substitutes. Here's the full code. Have I missed something?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# initializing webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="~~chromedriver.exe")
url = " https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/storage/lenovo-storage/s3200/70l8/parts/display/compatible."
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)

results = []

#getting breadcrumbs
bread1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='prod-catagory-name']")
bread2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='prod-catagory-name']/a")

#grabbing table data and navigating 
pages = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='page-container']/span[@class='icon-s-right active']/preceding-sibling::span[1]").text)
num = pages -1 

for _ in range(pages):
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div")
        for row in rows:
            parts = row.text
            results.append([url,bread1.text,parts])
        try: 
            for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='icon-s-down']"))):
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
                sleep(5)
                substitute = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='icon-s-up']//following::tr[3]/td[contains(@class,'enabled-border')]//div[text()]")))
                for sub in substitute:
                    subs = sub.text
                    results.append(subs)
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
        finally:
            try:
                pagination = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='page-container']/span[@class='icon-s-right active']").click()
                sleep(3)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('datacenter2.csv', index=False)
driver.quit()
```

The results were far from pleasing. I know am missing something within the loops. But am not sure what. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
This is the result I get :[image: The substitutes are what you see in rows 12 to 16]

I need to print the code alongside the numbers in the last column for each row it scrapes

Comment: Give please example of desired and current example

Comment: @Super Mario I have edited it and added the details.